# Prove that if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\int_{x}^{\infty}f(t)dt}{\int_{x}^{\infty}g(t)dt}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

We are given:

- $f$ and $g$ are two positive and continuous functions on an interval $[a,\infty)$.
- $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(t)dt$ and $\int_{a}^{\infty}g(t)dt$ are convergent.

Comment: You could make use of l'Hospital.

Comment: @BenS. since $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(t)dt<\infty$ and $f$ is positive $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}f(t)dt=0$. Same argument with $g$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$, we know for any $\epsilon > 0$. there exists $M > 0$, for all $x > M$, we have
$$ 1 -\epsilon < \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < 1 + \epsilon $$
Or
$$(1 -\epsilon)g(x) < f(x) < (1 + \epsilon) g(x)$$
Integrate it,
$$(1 -\epsilon)\int_x^{\infty}g(t)dt < \int_x^{\infty}f(t)dt < (1 + \epsilon)\int_x^{\infty}g(t)dt$$
Therefore,
$$1 -\epsilon < \frac{\int_x^{\infty}f(t)dt}{\int_x^{\infty}g(t)dt} < 1 + \epsilon$$
for $x > M$.

Comment: @runaraound very elegant proof

Comment: Not sure why I didn't try using the definition of a limit, but it seemed to work out very nicely here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1\implies\,\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;\exists\,R_n\in\Bbb R^+\;\text{ such that for}\;\;x>R_n\;,\;\;\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-1\right|<\frac1n\iff$$

$$\iff g(x)\left(1-\frac1n\right)<f(x)<g(x)\left(1+\frac1n\right)\implies$$

$$1{}\xleftarrow[\infty\leftarrow n]{}1-\frac1n=\frac{\int\limits_x^\infty g(t)\left(1-
\frac1n\right)dt}{\int\limits_x^\infty g(t)dt}\le\frac{\int\limits_x^\infty f(t)dt}{\int\limits_x^\infty g(t)dt}\le\frac{\int\limits_x^\infty g(t)\left(1+\frac1n\right)dt}{\int\limits_x^\infty g(t)dt}=1+\frac1n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

We can choose the above $\;R_n\;$ so as to have $\;x\to\infty\;$ when $\;n\to\infty\;$ . I think this poses no major problem.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since the integrals $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_a^\infty g(x)\,dx$ convege, then

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_x^\infty f(t)\,dt=0$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_x^\infty g(t)\,dt=0$$

Then, applying L'Hospital's rule, and applying the fundamental theorem of calculus, we find

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int_x^\infty f(t)\,dt}{\int_x^\infty g(t)\,dt}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{-f(x)}{-g(x)}=1$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Nicely simple.  +1

Comment: @RRL Thanks.  Much appreciative.  L'Hospital's Rule is often used without regard for easier approaches.  But in this case, its use was quite efficient.  By the way, I was going to write, I don't usually drink beer, but when I do I drink L'Hospital's.  But ... ;-))

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'Hopital but you can also prove it directly. Because of the limit given, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there's an $x_0$ such that if $t > x_0$ one has
$$(1 - \epsilon) g(t) < f(t) < (1 + \epsilon) g(t)$$
Integrating the above one obtains 
$$(1 - \epsilon)\int_{x_0}^{\infty} g(t)\,dt < \int_{x_0}^{\infty} f(t)\,dt < (1 - \epsilon)\int_{x_0}^{\infty} g(t)\,dt$$
This will hold if one replaces $x_0$ by any larger number too, so if $x > x_0$ one has
$$(1 - \epsilon)\int_{x}^{\infty} g(t)\,dt < \int_{x}^{\infty} f(t)\,dt < (1 - \epsilon)\int_{x}^{\infty} g(t)\,dt$$
This is the same as
$$(1 - \epsilon) < {\int_{x}^{\infty} f(t)\,dt \over \int_{x}^{\infty} g(t)\,dt} < (1 + \epsilon)$$
This gives the desired limit.

Comment: Similar solution as runaround's, which is quite elegant. Thanks for the help.